# How do I set the desktop background in python? (windows)

Tags: python, ctypes

This is what I'm trying:

```
import ctypes
import os
drive = "F:\\"
folder = "Keith's Stuff"
image = "midi turmes.png"
image_path = os.path.join(drive, folder, image)
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, image_path, 3)
```

Basicaly, this code is obviously supposed to set the desktop background to midi turmes.png, it changes the desktop, however, for some odd reason, it's always a green background (my personalized settings in windows is a green background behind the image) how do I fix this and make the desktop look like this?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRJ1H.png

Comment: have you tried with a JPG image instead of a PNG?

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  Also try setting argtypes and restype for the function.

Comment: yep, i tried that. and i'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: I'm playing with this on the shell. The command seems to change the background to solid color, instead of using the image (you can even open the background settings next to the shell and see it change live)

Comment: I think it has to do with Windows 10. I'm playing with the script, but it doesn't work for me either. Your code pops up on a few questions here on SO, but they all use it the same as you. Since it isn't working for me either, it's possible the Microsoft changed something in Windows 10 (maybe even the last update)

Comment: i actually have windows 8.1, but i still want this compatible for all windows OS's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me.  I'm using Windows 10 64-bit and Python 3.

```
import os
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

drive = 'c:\\'
folder = 'test'
image = 'midi turmes.png'
image_path = os.path.join(drive, folder, image)

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER  = 0x0014
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE    = 0x0001
SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x0002

def boolcheck(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ct.WinError(ct.get_last_error())
    return None

user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
SystemParametersInfo = user32.SystemParametersInfoW
SystemParametersInfo.argtypes = w.UINT, w.UINT, w.LPVOID, w.UINT
SystemParametersInfo.restype = w.BOOL
SystemParametersInfo.errcheck = boolcheck

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, image_path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
```

The important part is to make sure to use a Unicode string for `image_path` if using `SystemParametersInfoW`, and a byte string if using `SystemParametersInfoA`.  Remember that in Python 3 strings are default Unicode.

It is also good practice to set `argtypes` and `restype` as well.  You can even "lie" and set the third argtypes parameter to `c_wchar_p` for `SystemParametersInfoW` and then ctypes will validate that you are passing a Unicode string and not a byte string.

References:

- [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module documentation.
- [SystemParametersInfoW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow)
- [argtypes/restype/errcheck](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#foreign-functions)
- `import ctypes.wintypes as w; print(dir(w))`
- [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/) to locate `SPIF_*` constant values.

Comment: Can you point to a link that would explain what the hell? I've been writing scripts to do windows things for years, but the process always feels random. I try something, it doesn't work, then I google until I find a snippet that works. When I do this with most languages I actually learn something along the way, but with the weird names, convulted methods and horrifying mess that is the Windows API Docs I just can't make any sense of it

Comment: Now, [win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(action, param, winIn)](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__SystemParametersInfo_meth.html) 3 parameters

[LinkodeImageSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o3GR.png)