# 'SystemParametersInfo' function returns incorrect value when get the desktop wallpaper

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the function `SystemParametersInfo` to get the desktop wallpaper and it's assumed that when adding the action `SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER` to the function returns a string.

```
LPWSTR bgPath;
if(!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, bgPath, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE)){
     qDebug() << *bgPath;
     return;
}
qDebug()<< "an error occurred";
```

The problem is that the function returns a numeric value (ex: 50121) instead of a string.
Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: It don't understand why you would write this code. It's as if you didn't read the documentation. It says the following: *Retrieves the full path of the bitmap file for the desktop wallpaper. The pvParam parameter must point to a buffer to receive the null-terminated path string. Set the uiParam parameter to the size, in characters, of the pvParam buffer. The returned string will not exceed MAX_PATH characters. If there is no desktop wallpaper, the returned string is empty.*

Comment: So you got both parameters wrong, and also the file Al parameter is wrong. On top of everything else, you handle the return value incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use a WCHAR[] so it can write the name of the file into the buffer. And pass the size of the array so it can't write too much. And fix the if() statement, you already noticed that it returned FALSE to indicate failure.  And use GetLastError() to find out why it failed, always important to discover why winapi function calls don't work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you. I've read the documentation about that point as you exactly wrote, but I still don't understand because I don't use `winapi` too much, so, is it possible to give me an example of using `SystemParametersInfo` correctly?

Comment: Why don't you ask a colleague for help. Asking us to do your work for you ain't cool.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You are my colleagues at the critical moments.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not allocating any memory for `bgPath` for `SystemParametersInfo()` to fill in.

Per the `SPI_GETDESKTOPWALLPAPER` documentation:

> The `pvParam` parameter must point to a buffer to receive the null-terminated path string. Set the `uiParam` parameter to the size, in characters, of the `pvParam` buffer. The returned string will not exceed `MAX_PATH` characters.

Even if you were allocating a buffer, you are checking the return value of `SystemParametersInfo()` for failure instead of success. And you are dereferencing your string pointer, so at best you would output only the first character, not the whole string.

Use this instead:

```
WCHAR bgPath[MAX_PATH];

if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, MAX_PATH, bgPath, 0))
{
    qDebug() << bgPath;
    return;
}
qDebug() << "an error occurred";
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer. unfortunately, the function returns an address (ex: 0x28c1c0).

Comment: @LionKing does `qDebug()` accept Unicode strings to begin with? Or only ANSI strings? If the latter, then convert `bgPath` to ANSI using `WideCharToMultiByte()`, or use `SystemParametersInfoA()` with a `char[]` buffer

Comment: @LionKing: Since there is no `operator<<` overload for `QDebug` taking a `const wchar_t*`, lookup will match the generic pointer overload instead, taking a `const void*`. This will output the pointer value. If you want to dump a wide character string, you're going to have to construct a `QString` temporary first: `qDebug() << QString( bgPath );`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks. I've used a static member of `QString` called `QString::fromWCharArray()`  to convert the string.

Comment: what size buffer is recommended? and why? i've seen [someone use 200](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875514/9312988). i'm not sure if that's right. i know that path lengths can be 256 (or higher perhaps) (i found that out when a folders properties weren't showing the correct size of all the contents because it excluded files with long paths) and there's a way you can tell windows to use longer paths in the register.

Comment: @Puddle per the `SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER` documentation: "*The returned string will not exceed MAX_PATH characters. If there is no desktop wallpaper, the returned string is empty.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau i appreciate the reply, but that added absolutely nothing based on my question. everybody here knows what you just mentioned. my question was to imply that you should recommend what MAX_PATH should be also. for my little program, i've just gone with 512 to be safe. (i don't have long paths on my computer anyway, but i like completeness)

Comment: @Puddle `MAX_PATH` is defined by the Win32 API (in `windef.h`) as 260. `SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER` is not one of the APIs that allows longer paths.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you. you should include that in your answer. (looks like i was right in going above 256 ;))