# Change Windows 10 background in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, ctypes

I've been trying to find the best way to change the Windows 10 Desktop wallpaper through a python script. When I try to run this script, the desktop background turns to a solid black color.

```
import ctypes

path = 'C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\0200200220.jpg'

def changeBG(path):
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, path, 3)
    return;

changeBG(path)
```

What can I do to fix this? I'm using python3

Comment: I'm running macOS but check if you can use this as reference. https://www.techwalla.com/articles/script-to-change-desktop-background. It involves 2 steps. Changing the path to the desktop wallpaper you want and sending a system update command using user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True. This update command is included in most guides I've read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 64 bit windows, use:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW
```

for 32 bit windows, use:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA
```

If you use the wrong one, you will get a black screen. You can find out which version your using in **Control Panel -> System and Security -> System**.

You could also make your script choose the correct one:

```
import struct
import ctypes

PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\0200200220.jpg'
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20

def is_64bit_windows():
    """Check if 64 bit Windows OS"""
    return struct.calcsize('P') * 8 == 64

def changeBG(path):
    """Change background depending on bit size"""
    if is_64bit_windows():
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, PATH, 3)
    else:
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, PATH, 3)

changeBG(PATH)
```

**Update:**

I've made an oversight with the above. As [@Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878508/change-windows-10-background-in-python-3/53889041#comment94624531_53878546) demonstrated in the comments, it depends on ANSI and UNICODE path strings, not the OS type.

If you use the byte strings paths, such as `b'C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\0200200220.jpg'`, use:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA
```

Otherwise you can use this for normal unicode paths:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW
```

This is also highlighted better with argtypes in [@Mark Tolonen's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878508/change-windows-10-background-in-python-3/53889041#53889041) answer, and this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867820/python-difference-between-windows-systemparametersinfow-vs-systemparametersinf/44875514#44875514).

Comment: The real problem is not defining argtypes.  The A version takes a byte string for the 3rd parameter, and the W version takes a Unicode string.You can use both A and W regardless of OS type, if you call them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`SystemParametersInfoA` takes an ANSI string (`bytes` type in Python 3).

`SystemParametersInfoW` takes a Unicode string (`str` type in Python 3).

So use:

```
path = b'C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\0200200220.jpg'
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, path, 3)
```

or:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\0200200220.jpg'
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 3)
```

You can set the argtypes to do parameter checking.  The 3rd parameter is documented as `LPVOID` but you can be more specific for type checking:

```
from ctypes import *
windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW.argtypes = c_uint,c_uint,c_wchar_p,c_uint
windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA.argtypes = c_uint,c_uint,c_char_p,c_uint
```