# Pass in PIL image data into ctypes windll

Tags: dll, python-imaging-library, ctypes

I am creating an image in PIL to set as the desktop background using ctypes, however it is incredibly slow to save to a file then pass in the absolute path.

```
image.save('file.png')
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(0x14, 0, 'file.png', 0x2)
```

Is there anyway to directly pass in the image data, be it by casting to numpy array or bytes directly into the windll to speed up my code?

Comment: I don't think that interface will accept an actual image, only a file name.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011) for a serious flaw in your code. This is how it should be done: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40574622/4788546.